# how can create android calender event view

Tags: android, view, calendar

i want to create a view just like image. How can i accomplish this.I have seach about this but not able to create just like this view. Can any body help me.
I have create the calender but the unable to show the bars

Thanks[image]

Comment: I have found this usefully help in code.google.com But not able to accomplish this. [yadview](https://code.google.com/p/yadview/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Yadview library from this link : https://code.google.com/p/yadview

It loads, lays out and displays events. yadview is intended to be more robust in handling of events from various sources, rendering differently.

[image]

It works really good for me!

Comment: hi how to add event in this view

Answer (score -1):

there is a library that you can use:
https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid

Embedded as a fragment or shown as dialog
Set min/max date. The date outside min/max range is marked as disabled
Set disabled dates
Select dates fromDate to toDate
Client can listen to various events when user interacts with Calendar
Customize look and feel

Comment: I have already create a view of calender.Just want to help on creating the bar like diagram. which shows event is between 2 to 4 pm.
thanks